# Problem with github desktop: Current Branch ("unknown")

Tags: github-desktop

i'm kind new with git so i was using github desktop and i don't really know what is happening. I've been using for around 1.5 months for college and the repository that i was using for this whole time started to have this problem: [image]

My repository is still in github. I can acsess it and it shows the default branch (main) and all my files, but for someone reason i can't access it from github desktop
Does anyone already had a simillar problemn and could help me, please?

Comment: This particular behavior appears to be specific to github-desktop. The "unborn HEAD" notation in Git itself just means that you have no commits yet; presumably, though, you *do* have commits, and it's just a matter of convincing github-desktop (which is not Git, and not GitHub, it's a separate program from either of those, that I have never used myself) to use them.